# Numpy sampling function

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any function in numpy or scipy that for a given pdf, a point sampled from that distribution will be returned?

For example, I have a mixture of Gaussian distribution:

```
means = 0., 8.
stdevs = 1.0,1.0
weights = 0.75,0.25

pdfs = [p * norm.pdf(x, mu, sd) for mu, sd, p in zip(means, stdevs, weights)]
```

The graph for pdf and the histogram for points sampled from this distribution should look like: 
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this using numpy

```
import numpy as np
x_vals = np.random.normal(0., 1.0, 100)
y_vals = np.random.normal(8., 1.0, 100)
x_norm = [*x_vals, *y_vals]
```

Comment: What does the * before x_vals and y_vals mean over there? And it's a mixture of Gaussian not a multivariant Gaussian by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine multiple pdfs in such a way that you can still pass `x` to, you will need to create a new function.  One way to do this is to create a function returns returns a function with the weighted sum of the gaussians.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

def create_mixed_pdf(means, stdevs, weights):
    # this uses a lambda function to return the weighted sum of the pdfs at x
    return lambda x: sum([p*norm(mu, sd).pdf(x) for mu, sd, p in zip(means, stdevs, weights)])

# this sets `my_pdf` to be the combined pdf distributions
my_pdf = create_mixed_pdf(means, stdevs, weights)

# testing:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(-4, 12, .05)

plt.plot(x, my_pdf(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what I want to do is more than plotting the pdf, I also want to sample some data points from this pdf. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to take random sample from the distribution?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sampling from a random pdf is an interesting problem!!!
and is very easy.

```
# LETS CREATE SOME CUSTOM PDF AND CDF
x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
mu=1
s=0.5
pdf = (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*s**2))*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*s**2))/0.8 + (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*4*s**2))*np.exp(-(x-mu-3)**2/(2*4*s**2))/0.8
cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)
cdf = cdf/ cdf[-1]
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(x,pdf)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(x,cdf)
```

[Images:PDF and CDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOJD5.png)

```
# SAMPLE FROM CDF USING UNIFORM DISTRIBUTION
uniform_samples = np.random.uniform(0,1,100000)
index = []
for sample in uniform_samples:
  index.append(np.argmin(np.abs(cdf - sample)))
```

```
#Project theses samples from cdf to pdf 
pdf_samples = x[index]
plt.hist(pdf_samples, bins=100);
```

[Image: samples from custom pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIksy.png)